# Is there Inter_area texture minFilter in three.js like in opencv?

Tags: image-processing, three.js, textures, antialiasing

I have a three.js canvas to which I uploaded a 2730x4096 resolution image. I have given options to download different resolutions of images from the canvas. When I download a lower resoltuion image - say 960x1440 image, I get a very blurry image with jagged edges.

I tried to increase the sharpness by setting anisotropy to max(16 in my case) and also tried using map.minFilter= THREE.LinearFilter, which also sharpened the image further but the edges are still jagged.

I tried to run it through an FXAA anti aliasing composer, but the anti-aliasing is not great. May be I'm not giving correct parameters. 
All the while antialias from renderer is active (renderer.antialias=true)

When I try to do the same in opencv, I used cv2.INTER_AREA interpolation for downsizing the 2730x4096 image which gives me a very sharp images with absolutely no jagged edges.

So I was thinking if implementing INTER_AREA interpolation for the minFilter instead of THREE.LinearFilter might yield better results. Is there something existing already in three.js that I'm not utilizing, or if I have to use this new interpolation method, how to go about it?

Illustration:
PFA two files - one file is downloaded using three.js canvas directly at 960x1440 resolution (bottom one) and other is an image which is downsized from 2730x4096 to 960x1440 using opencv (top one). In the opencv downsized image, the details are sharper and the edges are cleaner than the three.js image. I'm starting to believe this is because of the INTER_AREA interpolation for downsizing in opencv. Is that replicable in three.js?

The original high resolution image can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zUZ61SCcxM6_L2Us9uvZkds6gw3Dq03A/view?usp=sharing)

[image: 960x1440 downsized from 2730x4096 in opencv]

[image: 960x1440 from three.js canvas]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your setup is, but by enabling `THREE.LinearFilter`, you're no longer using Mipmapping, which is very effective at downsampling large textures. The default is `LinearMipMapLinearFilter` but you have several other options, as outlined in the [texture constants docs page](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/constants/Textures). I've found that using anything but the default gives you crunchy textures.

Also, make sure you're enabling antialiasing with `renderer.antialias = true;` if you need it. Not sure if you're already doing this step, given the limited scope of the code in your question.

Comment: Hi, I have tried all the options from texture constants. LinearFilter and NearestFilter were giving me the sharpest details, while the edges became too jagged.

Comment: Ny question here is that starting from the same source image of 2730x4096 resolution, opencv gives much better results after downsizing to 960x1440 compared to same downsized image in three.js